# "Host key verification failed" on Gitlab_ci although ssh_key is present

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, ssh-keys, gitlab-ci-runner

"Host key verification failed." **on Gitlab_ci** when running "ssh name@server"

Here's a part of my gitlab_ci which is supposed to login to my server and run scripts from the repo:

```
script:
  - which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - ssh-add <(echo -e "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")


  - echo "debug"
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" # all is ok here, it'll be printed
  - echo "debug"


  # - here comes an error
  - (cat ./script/script1.sh) | ssh -t -t $SSH_USERNAME@$SSH_HOST
```

And the errror:

```
  Host key verification failed.
  ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Why the error? The variables are set.

**The private key does work when I'm doing the same thing manually from my local computer and Gitlab.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git error: "Host Key Verification Failed" when connecting to remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363553/git-error-host-key-verification-failed-when-connecting-to-remote-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh-keys%5D+%22Host+key+verification+failed.%22

Comment: @Oddamati did the answer solved your issue? because I'm facing a similar issue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In addition of [Git error: “Host Key Verification Failed” when connecting to remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13363553/6309), check your .known_hosts file.

If that same private key is working locally, that might be because, locally, your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file does [include the `ssh_keyscan`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29908140/6309) of the remote server you want to connect to.
Make sure your GitLab CI job does too.

Answer (score 3):

I hit the same wall today and resolved it.
My solution is adding a `-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no` option to the ssh.

I found out this problem has been caused by ssh asking you the question below and this isn't supposed to appear in logs.

```
The authenticity of host 'xxx' can't be established.
ESDSA key fingerprint is xxxxxxxxxxxxx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

The option `-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no` will suppress this so your ssh might work well.

I hope it will help people who have the same problem.

Comment: It would work, yes, but at what cost? Removing this security check is generally not recommended (https://security.stackexchange.com/a/40002).