# Jenkins Service Cannot access GIt repository Ussing SSH

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, continuous-integration

I have installed Jenkins on remote server (ubuntu) and created a project. (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-jenkins-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Then I created key pair using `ssh-keygen` and added public key to the bitbucket project. (https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html) Now there is a capability to execute git commands on terminal of remote server such as `git clone`. and it works fine.

But the problem is when I add git repository to the jenkins **Source Code Management section** it shows an error of permission denied. Can anyone explain how can I set git repository on **jenkin'ssource code management section** correctly. I have added a SS of the error message.

[image: Screen shot of Error]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git error: "Host Key Verification Failed" when connecting to remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363553/git-error-host-key-verification-failed-when-connecting-to-remote-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh%5D+host+key+verification+failed

Answer (score 0):

The error points to the host key missing in known_hosts file. Login to the jenkins server as user ‘jenkins’. Checkout you repo using ssh url, you will see a SSH warning when connecting to a new host for first time. Enter yes. The host key for bitbucket.org will now be added to the ~/.ssh/known_hosts file

That should resolve the error you are seeing