# Not able to use git fetch all in jenkins due to Host key error

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

I am tring to pull the all code from code-cloud using git fetch all. I have done the proper ssh keysetup and tested it. But while using in jenkins free-style job , during fetch it is failing with host key verificiation error.

```
Code:
+ /usr/bin/git fetch --all

Error:
Fetching origin
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Please help us on this. The key-setup is fine and code-cloud url is also fine.
```

Comment: What does git remote show origin say?

Comment: /usr/bin/git remote show origin : Host key verification failed fatal: Could not read from remote repo . Please make sure you have right access rights and repo exists

Comment: Another test: `git config --list --show-origin`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git error: "Host Key Verification Failed" when connecting to remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363553/git-error-host-key-verification-failed-when-connecting-to-remote-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Host+key+verification+failed.

Comment: Reply to git config --list --show-origin:
file:.git/config       core.repositoryformatversion=0
file:.git/config       core.filemode=true
file:.git/config       core.bare=false
file:.git/config       core.logallrefupdates=true
file:.git/config