# Push to GitHub from Team City build step

Tags: git, github, teamcity

I have a build step in Team City which generates documentation which I want to commit with git and then push to GitHub.

I am using ssh to connect to GitHub and doing the following:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Update docs"
git push origin refs/heads/localbranch:refs/heads/remotebranch
```

I am getting:

```
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Should this approach work or do I need to try something else?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363553/git-error-host-key-verification-failed-when-connecting-to-remote-repository

Comment: could you please provide more details otherwise nothing is clear. how do you add VCS? how you add ssh_keys and e.t.c.

Comment: I created a Git vcs root using the ssh url from GitHub for fetch&push.The ssh key was generated on the server and added through the "Upload ssh keys" menu in Team City

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing the host key or the host key has changed.
See:[SSH connection problem with “Host key verification failed…” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45679/ssh-connection-problem-with-host-key-verification-failed-error)