# How to run Satis on a remote server?

Tags: git, ssh, composer-php, satis

There is a command to run Satis: `php bin/satis build satis.json response`

Satis itself lies on the server, for example, `example.com/satis`

How to run a command on a server remotely?

I tried to make a script with the command `shell_exec('php bin/satis build satis.json response/')` but encountered an error when Satis cannot log in to Git:

```
Scanning packages
Failed to clone the git@gitlab.com:project/project.git repository, try running in interactive mode so that you can enter your credentials

In Git.php line 354:

  Failed to execute git clone --mirror 'git@gitlab.com:project/project
  .git' '/var/www/.composer/cache/vcs/git-gitlab.com-project.git/'                                                                         

  Cloning into bare repository '/var/www/.composer/cache/vcs/git-gitlab.com-project.git'...                                                
  Host key verification failed.                                                
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.                                

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights                          
  and the repository exists.                                                   


build [--repository-url [REPOSITORY-URL]] [--repository-strict] [--no-html-output] [--skip-errors] [--stats] [--] [ [ [...]]]
```

Where is a problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git error: "Host Key Verification Failed" when connecting to remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363553/git-error-host-key-verification-failed-when-connecting-to-remote-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh%5D+Host+key+verification+failed

Answer (score 0):

> Host key verification failed.

Probably your command is not executed with the same user as the one managing satis on the server.

That means `$HOME` is not the same, and [`$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts`](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-fix-the-error-host-key-verification-failed/) (used to verify the host key of the remote host) is not there or not the same.

Try at least `shell_exec('id -a; env')` to check out what user/environment is seen through a `shell_exec()` call.