# Jenkins pipeline Git error: “Host Key Verification Failed” when connecting to remote repository

Tags: bash, git, jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am using my PC as a server to build my Jenkins script with declarative pipeline.

when running a git clone on the git bash, it works well:

```
$ git clone ssh://guillaumed@myserver.com:29418/myProjects/thisProject.git ThisFirmware
Cloning into 'ThisFirmware'...
remote: Counting objects: 889, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (203/203)
Receiving objects:  79% (121769/152721), 48.11 MiB | 10.35 MiB/s
```

but running it on the same machine through pipelining :

```
sh "git clone ssh://guillaumed@myserver.com:29418/myProjects/thisProject.git ThisFirmware"
```

gives me the following error

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ git clone ssh://guillaumed@myserver.com:29418/myProjects/thisProject.git ThisFirmware
Cloning into 'ThisFirmware'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

any hints?

To be sure I was using the same key, thanks to Jens, the pipeline script couldn't find the key.

- Doing `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` on the pipeline, resulted in `+ cat /c/windows/system32/config/systemprofile/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  cat: /c/windows/system32/config/systemprofile/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: No such file or directory`
- So I copied the ssh file from my guillaumed user ssh path to the SYSTEM ssh path but I can't use it if i'm logged in with SYSTEM user instead of guillaumed user.

what do I have to do?

this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363553/git-error-host-key-verification-failed-when-connecting-to-remote-repository) didn't help.

Comment: You are sure you use the same ssh key?

Comment: how to be sure?

Comment: You are running on same user?  Use -v to check which key you are using.

Comment: i did ```cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub``` on the pipeline and i says ```+ cat /c/windows/system32/config/systemprofile/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
cat: /c/windows/system32/config/systemprofile/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: No such file or directory``` what do I have to do?

Comment: thanks, the username is SYSTEM instead of guillaumed... how can I change it?

Comment: I tried copying the ssh key but it won't work because i'm logging as a different user...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you can't checkout with ssh if you are logged as SYSTEM.

To checkout as "thisUser":

**You'll need to configure your Jenkins.**

1/ add a user "thisUser"

2/ add user's ssh credentials "thisUser-ssh-credentials"

3/ use ssh-agent plugin https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+Agent+Plugin

**Then configure your pipeline**

```
dir(server_workspace) 
{
    sshagent(credentials: ['thisUser-ssh-credentials'] ) 
    {
        sh "git clone ssh://thisUser@domain.com:port/yourProjects/thisProject.git"
    }
}
```