# How to clone repository using SSH in EC2 userdata?

Tags: bash, git, ssh

I am trying to clone a git repository while my EC2 instance boots up. Following is the code I have till now:

```
echo "$ssh_key" | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' > /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa 
chmod 400 /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa
git clone git@github.com:xyz.git
```

But the code always fails while cloning the repository. Following is the error I get:

```
Agent pid 2398
Identity added: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa)
Cloning into 'test-folder'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How to do I get around this? The keys are proper, and I am able to clone the repository when I manually run the command from the cli, but fails in userdata of EC2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh%5D+Host+key+verification+failed

Comment: Hint: A host key is a different key.

Comment: @phd Have already tried the above solution. Didn't work. Throws the same error.

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29380765/147356) to the same question will solve your problem.