# Jenkins pipeline fails git clone using sshagent plugin?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins v2.164.3, ssh agent plugin 1.19

I created a new Ubuntu build node, called it `test-fleet` arbitrarily. I have the following file in the node

```
/home/ubuntu/.gitconfig
------------------------
[user]
(tab)name = myUser
(tab)email = myUser@myemail.com

$ ls -al .gitconfig
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   58 Jan 25 04:27 .gitconfig
```

Now I have a Jenkins pipeline that does this

```
node('test-fleet') {
   stage('test git') {
     sshagent(credentials: ['myUser-creds']) {
       sh """
          export GIT_SSH_COMMAND=\"ssh -v\"
          git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:project/myrepo.git
       """
     }
   }
}
```

I get this in my job's console

```
[ssh-agent] Using credentials myUser-creds (Bitbucket credentials)
[ssh-agent] Looking for ssh-agent implementation...
[ssh-agent]   Exec ssh-agent (binary ssh-agent on a remote machine)
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-V4G1oYutEMCW/agent.16446
SSH_AGENT_PID=16448
Running ssh-add (command line suppressed)
ssh-agent
Identity added: /home/jenkins/workspace/Utilities/Playground/test-ec2-fleet-ssh@tmp/private_key_2248848783998450720.key (/home/jenkins/workspace/Utilities/Playground/test-ec2-fleet-ssh@tmp/private_key_2248848783998450720.key)
Cloning into 'myrepo'...

+ git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:project/myrepo.git
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [18.205.93.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version conker_d603cef0bf app-133
debug1: no match: conker_d603cef0bf app-133
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.org:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:zzXQOXSRBEiUtuE8AikJYKwbHaxvSc0ojez9YXaGp1A
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I know I'm using the correct creds, and that the repo exists. I have another build node, and it works on THAT node, so I know my Jenkins is set up correctly, and the problem is on the new build node.

Any clues on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Check first the same key works when doing a `git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:project/myrepo.git` in a session using the same user as the one running Jenkins.

And check the `myUser-creds` is the actual passphrase (not password: passphrase) protecting the SSH private key. Where it comes to SSH, the is no "credentials" as in username/password.

Comment: Thanks. `myUser-creds` is just the name of the credentials defined in the Jenkins credentials console, which are an ssh pub/priv key pair.

Comment: @ChrisF OK: is your private ssh key passphrase protected? In other word, do you need the ssh agent?

Comment: No it's NOT paraphrase protected

Comment: @ChrisF You could add an `env GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v'`, to see what is going one.

Comment: y that helped - it's not seeing a private key in the `/home/ubuntu/.ssh` dir. But I thought that's what the sshagent() does, although sometimes I don't see the `Identity added ...` line. WT...???

Comment: It can happen if Jenkins is not running with the same user as the one with the keys. Or if the Jenkins SSH credentials has not reference the private key.

Comment: But that's what the `sshagent(credentials: ['myUser-creds'])` ensures.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check which user owns the Jenkins. You can find it out by listing the owner of jenkins install directory (/var/lib/jenkins is the default). Then log in with that user and check out .ssh folder for that user. As Jenkins is using SSH for the checkout, based on this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363553/git-error-host-key-verification-failed-when-connecting-to-remote-repository) you should have a problem in $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts. Follow the guidelines for the link provided **for the correct user running jenkins** to make git checkout work. The problem is that `myUser` actually does not have any ssh repository to be able to check the ssh keys. Either create `myUser` in your machine and add `.ssh` folder, or use another user.

Comment: I'm running as user ubuntu (`whoami` shows that) when the job runs, but because of the `.gitconfig`, the ssh-user is actually `myUser`. Note that I'm not building a ~/.ssh/know_hosts file, which can be a clue.

Comment: Try changing the user to "ubuntu" in your .gitconfig file. See what is the result

Comment: Changing the user to `ubuntu` did help, and i didn't expect it to.

Comment: The problem is that `myUser` actually does not have any ssh repository to be able to check the ssh keys. Either create `myUser` in your machine and add `.ssh` folder, or use another user.

Comment: but i have another Ubuntu box running that is set up similarly, and i don't have issues there. that is, no user `myUser` on it either. that's what bugs me.

Comment: Well, there is a difference, for sure. Most of the times problems in this area come from permissions, different users running different services, etc. As this happened to me before, I mention this scenario : During your previous ubuntu box setup, you might have done some extra work that might have seem trial-and-error and has been overlooked for the new setup but actually played a key role. For me it was a chmod change I had for one of my test machines. Took me a week to find it lol.

Comment: for sure there's a difference. I said `similar` not the same.

Comment: You're right. You have to find the change to find out the root cause. I would appreciate it a lot if you mention the difference below this question, after finding it.

Comment: Getting nearer. I copied the `known_hosts` file on the working Ubuntu machine to the non-working one, and it worked. But how come new machine is NOT creating a `known_hosts` file on its own?

Comment: Maybe it does not have permission to write in `.ssh` folder. Only the owner can access that.