# Pushing commits to an SSH-cloned repo via VS Code on WSL returns "Host key verification failed" - it's ok on HTTPS

Tags: windows, git, ssh, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm on a Windows 10 machine and I have both Git Bash and Ubuntu for Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) installed. When I use GitHub's official desktop app to clone a repo via HTTPS everything works fine and I can push my commits via Visual Studio Code with no problems whatsoever. I then try to clone a repo via SSH with Hyper (WSL Bash) and get this:

```
The authenticity of host 'domain.com (a.b.c.d)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is XX:XX:...:XX.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

After answering yes and openning that repo in VS Code and try to push my new changes to GitHub, I get this error:
[Git: Host key verification failed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlfKJ.png)

And this is what I get as Git Log in Output:
[Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Icm1e.png)

I have set up my SSH key on WSL using [this method](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/sharing-ssh-keys-between-windows-and-wsl-2/) and I didn't set up any passphrase. I tried this on my brother's PC which is exactly set up like mine and it worked just fine. I would appreciate any help!

**UPDATE:** I typed `ssh -T git@github.com` in Hyper and got this as an answer: `You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

**P.S.** I'm a newbie in programming and stackoverflow, so please be concise and give me step by step instructions. The more you use technical terms, the more I'll probably get lost!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git error: "Host Key Verification Failed" when connecting to remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363553/git-error-host-key-verification-failed-when-connecting-to-remote-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh%5D+Host+key+verification+failed

Answer (score 0):

Try first, for that new push, to do it in command line:

```
cd c:\path\to\local\repo
git status
git log
git remote -v
git push -u origin master
```

Make sure that:

- `git status` is clean (no pending changes)
- `git log` shows you at least one commit
- `git remote -v` shows you as origin the URL of your remote GitHub repository
  (as an SSH URL `git@github.com:<you>/<yourRepo>`)

Then push, and go back to VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

Should be faster than the other solution:

1. In vscode open a new terminal of type "Command Prompt"
2. Run: `git push` and accept the new key when prompted.

This will store the remote key for future use.