# Host key verification failed on raspberry pi

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I already added the keys to gitlab-ci

````
 $ cd /home/pi/dashboard
 $ git fetch
 Host key verification failed.
 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
 and the repository exists.```
````

Answer (score 1):

You could try and [scan for your gitlab-ci server first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13364116/6309)

```
ssh-keygen -R domain.com
ssh-keyscan -t rsa domain.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

(REplace '`domain.com`' by your gitlab-ci server)

Then try your `git fetch` again.