# Npm always showing me npm ERR! when I try to install anything

Tags: node.js, npm, ionic4

Please I need your help whenever I try to install anything with npm I always get errors please help me.
[image: Error image]

Comment: It's possibly a permissions take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363553/git-error-host-key-verification-failed-when-connecting-to-remote-repository to see if it helps

Answer (score 1):

### Update

From what read from the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/cli) you should install the `@ionic/cli`

```sh
$ npm install -g @ionic/cli
```

From the docs:

> If there was a previous installation of the Ionic CLI, it will need to be uninstalled due to a change in package name.

```sh
$ npm uninstall -g ionic
$ npm install -g @ionic/cli
```

You may want to add debug info while installing e.g.:

```sh
$ npm install -dd -g @ionic/cli
```

From your screenshot not sure if there is an error with your GIT config, or permissions to install the ionic cli globally on your machine...

---

### Outdated

There should not be a space between `ionic` and `@4`, you should run e.g.:

```sh
npm install -g ionic@4
```

Comment: @Alswell i updated this answer, not sure if it helps but from what i read from the ionic cli docs you should be installing the `@ionic/cli` package and not the `ionic` package.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with command like this *npm install -g ionic@{{version}}*.
In the place of version you should put your prefered version.

Comment: It's not working. Like anything i try to install with npm won't install