# How to set SSH on GitHub using Ed25519 algorithm in Colab?

Tags: git, github, ssh, google-colaboratory, ssh-keys

[Similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363553/git-error-host-key-verification-failed-when-connecting-to-remote-repository/29380765) look outdated compared to [official guide](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection). I do the following in `Colab`:

```
# Generating a new SSH key
!ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

```
Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_ed25519.
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub.
```

Then I copy-paste the content of `id_ed25519.pub` `ssh-ed25519 ..... your_email@example.com` to [new SSH Key window](https://github.com/settings/ssh/new).

And test connection fails:

```
!ssh -T git@github.com
```

```
Host key verification failed.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `!ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts` See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13364116/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh%5D+Host+key+verification+failed

Comment: This returns an error `No such file or directory`. Can you share complete working example?

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're seeing, “Host key verification failed,” indicates that the remote server is unknown.  Normally, in such a case, OpenSSH will prompt you with the fingerprint of the remote server and ask you to verify it.  The official guide contains a [link to the GitHub SSH key fingerprints](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints).

However, in this case, you're running the command from another program without a TTY, so OpenSSH can't prompt you.  You'll need to attempt to invoke the command from a terminal, then verify the fingerprint and then things should work.

Comment: Thank you, do you know how to do that in `Colab`?

Comment: I don't.  You won't be able to just shell out here; you'll need a real terminal.

Comment: You can add `-o StrickHostKeyChecking=no` to the `ssh` command line - only do that when you are sure you can trust your connection to github.

Comment: I didn't mention that because that's not a secure approach and it's impossible to know for certain that the connection isn't being intercepted when you're making it over the public Internet.

Comment: If you don't want to skip host key checking, do the `ssh` thing from a real terminal, confirm, and let it save the host key to your `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.  Then write some code in Colab to append the new line to the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` at runtime before the `ssh` gets executed.

Comment: @bk2204 Agreed. I thought it would be better for OP to be aware of both the option and the risk.