# Unable to clone a private repo from github

Tags: git, github

I am following this tutorial - [link](https://github.com/tradingview/charting-library-tutorial/blob/master/documentation/home.md)

In this, you need access to a private repo called `charting_library`, which I do.

As written in the documentation,  `The Charting Library is free, but its code is in the private repository on GitHub. Make sure that you have access to this repository: https://github.com/tradingview/charting_library/.` I don't see any error but I can see the code here.

So following the documentation, when I run this

```
git clone https://github.com/tradingview/charting-library-tutorial.git
```

The repo gets cloned, no problem. But then when I run the next command

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

I get the following error

```
Cloning into 'C:/coding/charting-library-tutorial/charting_library_clonned_data'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'git@github.com:tradingview/charting_library.git' into submodule path 'C:/coding/charting-library-tutorial/charting_library_clonned_data' failed
Failed to clone 'charting_library_clonned_data'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into 'C:/coding/charting-library-tutorial/charting_library_clonned_data'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'git@github.com:tradingview/charting_library.git' into submodule path 'C:/coding/charting-library-tutorial/charting_library_clonned_data' failed
Failed to clone 'charting_library_clonned_data' a second time, aborting
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git error: "Host Key Verification Failed" when connecting to remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363553/git-error-host-key-verification-failed-when-connecting-to-remote-repository)

Comment: @Matt I checked out this answer before answering this question. I am not using SSH keys here, but still I ran ```ssh-keyscan -t rsa domain.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
``` and it still did not work.

Comment: @Matt just to verify, can you please tell me what should be the "domain.com" in the above code for my case?

Comment: The referenced repository in [.gitmodules](https://github.com/tradingview/charting-library-tutorial/blob/master/.gitmodules) is using SSH. The domain in this case would be `github.com`. Did you remove the existing entry with `ssh-keygen -R github.com`?

Comment: Check your `.gitmodules` file, it contains the URL(s) that the `git submodule` command will try to connect to. When I use submodules, I try to use relative URLs in there, e.g., `url = ../otherrepo.git`, so that Git uses the same method to authenticate to the server as I did for the main repo, and so that whenever I move stuff from one server to another, as long as I move the submodules too, it all stays coherent. Of course, that only works if all your repos live on the same Git server.

Comment: @joanis I ran ```ssh-keygen -R github.com``` -> ```ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts``` ->```git submodule update --init --recursive```  it still gives me the same error. Is there any other command that I should put after this?

Comment: @Matt is that above comment fine? or should I add something else too?