# Getting error during composer install inside docker

Tags: docker, composer-php

Getting the below error while running composer install command in docker :

```
 In Git.php line 471:
#0 14.00
#0 14.00   Failed to execute git clone --mirror -- 'git@github.com:Laravel-Backpack/PR
#0 14.00   O.git' '/root/.composer/cache/vcs/git-github.com-Laravel-Backpack-PRO.git/'
#0 14.00
#0 14.00   Cloning into bare repository '/root/.composer/cache/vcs/git-github.com-Lara
#0 14.00   vel-Backpack-PRO.git'...
#0 14.00   Host key verification failed.
#0 14.00   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
#0 14.00
#0 14.00   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
#0 14.00   and the repository exists.
```

My docker file:

```
FROM php:8.2.8-apache-bullseye

# Use the default production configuration
#RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

# apache configs + document root
ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

# mod_rewrite for URL rewrite and mod_headers for .htaccess extra headers like Access-Control-Allow-Origin-
RUN a2enmod rewrite && a2enmod ssl && a2enmod socache_shmcb
# RUN sed -i '/SSLCertificateFile.*snakeoil\.pem/c\SSLCertificateFile \/etc\/ssl\/certs\/mycert.crt' /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf && sed -i '/SSLCertificateKeyFile.*snakeoil\.key/cSSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/mycert.key\' /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
RUN a2ensite default-ssl



# install and update php packages and extensions

RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y libzip-dev openssl zip unzip git libonig-dev libicu-dev libmemcached-dev \
&& pecl install memcached \
&& docker-php-ext-configure intl \
&& docker-php-ext-install zip intl pdo mbstring mysqli pdo_mysql \
&& docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql memcached


# install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
    && composer --no-scripts --ansi --version --no-interaction

# copy composer related files first and then run composer install
WORKDIR /var/www/html


COPY ./src/auth.json /root/.composer
COPY ./src/config.json /root/.composer

COPY ./src/composer.json ./src/composer.lock*  ./
RUN composer install --no-autoloader --ansi --no-interaction


# copy files from src folder to var/www/html. 
 WORKDIR /var/www/html
 COPY ./src .

# Run composer dump autoload
RUN composer dump-autoload -o \
 && chown -R :www-data /var/www/html \
    && chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/storage /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache


CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80;

EXPOSE 80
```

Part of my composer.json file contain reference to the repository for backpacklaravel:

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "description": "xxx",
  "license": "Proprietary",
  "type": "project",
   "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "http://repo.backpackforlaravel.com/"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": "^8.2",
    "ext-dom": "*",
    "ext-filter": "*",
```

I have tried placing auth.json file in the src folder of the project (The same folder as the composer.json file)

Also I have added the below config in composer.json file

```
 },
  "config": {
    "allow-plugins": {
      "ergebnis/composer-normalize": true
    },
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "auth-files": [
            "auth.json"           
        ]
  },
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git error: "Host Key Verification Failed" when connecting to remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363553/git-error-host-key-verification-failed-when-connecting-to-remote-repository)

Comment: yes, using the https url instead of giturl in the composerlock.json helped to fix my issue.  Example like below:
git url: 'https://github.com/username/repositoryname.git' instead of git@github.com:user/repositoryname.git. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the https url instead of giturl in the composerlock.json helped to fix my issue.
Example- using the https url: 'https://github.com/username/repositoryname.git' instead of git@github.com:user/repositoryname.git.
Thanks