# managing multiple ssh keys on heroku

Tags: heroku, ssh

so I have a couple of ssh keys that are used for other accounts that I have. I now need to  be able to clone a heroku repository on my computer. I created a new ssh key and used heroku keys:add to add it to my heroku account. However when I try and clone the repository I get this error: 
`Your key with fingerprint: .... is not authorized to access rural-visions. fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly`

I've heard that I need to create a config file in the .ssh folder, but I don't know what to put into there.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I sometimes have to work with a bunch of heroku accounts, and have run into this. Here's what I usually do:

- Clear identities

  ```
  $ ssh-add -D
  ```
- *ssh-add* the key that I need for the current account

  ```
  $ ssh-add ~/.ssh/an_account_key
  ```
- Now I can push to my heroku app

  ```
  $ git push heroku-remote master
  ```

Of course, this assumes that the key has been added to the heroku account already. You can do that with:

```
$ heroku keys:add
```

The correct way to solve this is with an SSH configuration in *~/.ssh/config*, but that's a bit much for me since I only switch accounts occasionally.

Googling about the SSH configuration file should turn up plenty of results, but here's some that might help:

- [SSH config - same host but different keys and usernames](https://superuser.com/questions/366649/ssh-config-same-host-but-different-keys-and-usernames)
- [Specify an SSH key for git push for a given domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927750/specify-an-ssh-key-for-git-push-without-using-ssh-config)
- [Simplify Your Life With an SSH Config File](http://nerderati.com/2011/03/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/)

Comment: if you get "ssh-add: Could not open a connection to your authentication agent” try: eval `ssh-agent`