# Unable to push to heroku using pycharm git

Tags: git, heroku, pycharm

[image]

I'm working on a pycharm/django project. my git repository has been added and commited but when I try to push , the error says "no tracked branch. I've tried:

```
$ git remote                                                                      
heroku
(r1)
/f/envs/r1/driver1 (master)
$ git remote show heroku
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '********' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.    

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Can someone advise me on what to do next?

Comment: The error seems to say your public key has been denied -`Permission denied (publickey)`. Has your public key been added to heroku and does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with PyCharm, but rather you haven't added your SSH key to Heroku. [This](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys) will help you fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks, That did help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752908/managing-multiple-ssh-keys-on-heroku and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752908/managing-multiple-ssh-keys-on-heroku did as well