# error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing

Tags: android, git, github

I have a git [repository](https://github.com/aniket91/Android) . I have a GUI client in Windows and EGit in Eclipse ADT. Generally I edit in Eclipse ADT and use the GUI Client to update the Github repo. First I commit (which creates a buffer) and then when I sync it uploads it to my actual repo.

Now I have clone my repo on Linux(CentOS 6.4). Everything is setup. I changed some file. Then I used `git add` and `git commit -m "message" -a` command and it worked fine. But my actual github repo was not updated. After bit of googling I figured out that we have to explicitly provide `git push` command. After which I am getting

```
[aniket@localhost Android]$ git push
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://github.com/aniket91/Android.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

What is going wrong? There is no firewall or proxy and I have close by iptables service. Has anyone encountered this scenario before? What should be done?

After following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed) answer (which kind of worked I got following error)

```
[aniket@localhost Android]$ git push origin master
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.130)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.252.130' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [answer you mention](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7438313/6309) suggests to change the url from an https one to an ssh one.

That would only work if you have a `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, with the latter (public key) published in your [GitHub ssh keys](https://github.com/settings/ssh).

Check your [Egit ssh configuration](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Remote#Eclipse_SSH_Configuration).

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/8/87/Egit-0.6-003-SshPreferences.png]

For step by step procedure as of how to generate SSH key and set it in your GitHub setting [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) is the link.

Comment: I want to do it command line using **git push origin master**

Comment: @AniketThakur then check your ssh config: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7927828/6309

Comment: Thanks the main part was generating SSH key and storing that in your github settings. Step by step --> https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the cause was that I was using https git access under my linux box. Pull was ok, while push ended with error. The solution was to switch to ssh access, ex:

So first read remote url:

```
$ git config --get remote.origin.url

https://github.com/yourname/project.git
```

if you see https then change it to ssh, copy proper url from your github project www, and call:

```
$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:yourname/project.git
```

you might still need to put (and maybe also generate) .ssh public key to github. For that look into VonC answer.

Answer (score 0):

So i faced the same problem with git to push the content to repository.

---

Error info:

error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://github.com/bhanurhce/rhel6-exapmpleserver.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed

---

**Work around for me**:

This error is majorly due to the LOGIN credentials from your local machine in the git hub.
You have to provide the username & password of github

Add username: **$ git config --global user.name "bhanurhce"** 
Username should be github's user account.

Confirm the username: **$ git config user.name**

once you try to push then it will ask for password:

**$ git push -u origin master**
Password:(provide your github's password.)

issue will be solved.

Even if you still get **error for askpass**:

Error info:
[root@virtual-master git]# git push -u origin master

(gnome-ssh-askpass:47356): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Then just solve it by command: $ **unset SSH_ASKPASS**

All will work fine. Hope it helps..

Thanks!!