# git push with ssh to server , public key error

Tags: git, ssh, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

I have ec2 server with ubuntu 12.04, I have added one more user "git" to server. Generated ssh key and uploaded to both users .ssh directory. So now i can access my server as

```
ssh ubuntu@example.com
ssh git@example.com
```

I have created a bare repository to `/opt/git/gitpg.git`  and added this as remote to my local repository as

```
sudo git remote add deploy ubuntu@example.com:/opt/git/gitpg.git
```

When i tried to push to this repository, it shows authentication error.

```
sudo git push deploy master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927750/specify-an-ssh-key-for-git-push-without-using-ssh-config), but it also doesn't work.

Can anyone please suggest what may be the possible reason ?

**Update**

When i tried `git push deploy master` instead of `sudo git push deploy master` it succeed to connect but unable to push due to permission.

```
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 356 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ubuntu@example.com:/opt/git/gitpg.git
   d6cc9c3..25ddaa4  master -> master
error: unable to create directory for .git/refs/remotes/deploy/master
error: Cannot lock the ref 'refs/remotes/deploy/master'.
```

**Update 2**

I changed local directory permission to current user now it working without sudo.
But i still don't know why it is nor working with sudo.

Comment: Are you sure you have put the correct public key that you generated in your git server?

Comment: I am able to login without defining pem file, as ssh ubuntu@example.com

Comment: Are you able to create directories in the server when you login through ssh?

Comment: @Banago, yes, i have given chown to ubuntu user for bare repo.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your public key in the server in `.ssh/authorized_keys` or use another protocol like this:

```
ssh://ubuntu@example.com/opt/git/gitpg.git
```

Comment: Thanks @Banago, when i use ssh:// it says ssh: `Could not resolve hostname example.com:: Name or service not known`

Comment: Yes, I had put an extra colon on the example. You need it only when you specify a port.