# Bitbucket master branch to website

Tags: git, repository, push, bitbucket, git-branch

I'm new to bitbucket and git. I have a stage branch and a master branch.
The stage branch is on my localhost, so I can instantly see changes I make to my website.
I'd like to connect my master branch to a domain name or something.
So when I type domain.com, that I can see my master branch. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to ssh into your domain and git clone your project, then whenever you are happy with a change that you have made locally, you can login to your server and do a git pull to pull in all of your changes. Should be simple enough as most hosting sites provide ssh access.

Comment: So I have do do this manually? Is there a way to automatically fetch the latest version of the master branch?

Comment: You can use something like webhook http://www.webhook.com/ which you can use to automatically pull in your branches on a push, but to be honest, there's not much point in doing this as it only takes 2 minutes to log in to your sever and pull and you wont necessarily pull on every push as you may be half way through making adding a new feature for example

Comment: That's true, but logging in to the server requires like 3 passwords so I was hoping for some automated solution

Comment: Do you have a tutorial or something that I can follow?

Comment: I will have a look on the interwebs for you now

Comment: Thanks, I think I found my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927750/specify-an-ssh-key-for-git-push-for-a-given-domain. at least for connection to git.

Comment: YOu may want to have a look at git hooks http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks may be your best chance