# GitLab cannot push to remote - SSH key missing - generic SSH entry in .ssh/config

Tags: ssh, gitlab

After creating a new repo (local + remote), I am trying to push commits. However I get an issue with the SSH key

In my ~/.ssh/config , I have an entry for gitlab defined as

```
Host MyRepoJD
HostName gitlab.myrepo.ninja
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitlab_myRepo/johnDoe
```

when I try to push from my ruby script, to the newly created repo in gitlab   ( gran_torino_sa/mar_arch   group: gran_torino_sa  project: mar_arch) it's failing as there is no entry for this newly created repo...

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname    
gitlab.myrepo.ninja:gran_torino_sa/mar_arch.git: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Is there a way to define only ONE entry for any group/project created or is it mandatory to add an entry for each new group/project?

Answer (score 1):

myrepoafter debugging again ... found the solution in this post

"Specify an SSH key for git push for a given domain"
[Specify an SSH key for git push for a given domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927750/specify-an-ssh-key-for-git-push-for-a-given-domain)

```
Host gitlab_as_johndoe
  HostName gitlab.myrepo.ninja
  User git
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitlab_myrepo/johndoe
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

and using

```
  git remote add origin git@gitlab_as_johndoe:gran_torino_sa/mar_arch.git"
```

did the trick...