# How to open git config file from command prompt - git shell?

Tags: git, github, command, config, command-prompt

I am using multiple git accounts from the same computer. I want to change settings for the accounts. Searched google, but wasn't able to find the command that helps to open the config file.

EDIT : It looks like there are different ways and config files to access github.

The answer given by @Altius and here : gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996

I tried both - after setting up SSH keys for my second account, but both failed to push repository to my second account , but I can see repositories being pushed to my first - default account irrespective of what changes I make to any of the config files.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114111/where-does-git-config-global-get-written-to) help you? Or maybe the [git docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped, but what I am trying do is this : https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996

No matter what I do, I am not able to access my 2nd account - the account which was made later.

1. I created new SSH key for the second account.
2. Copied and added it to my second account.
3. Tried both - the method given by @Altius and in the above link. Both failed to push repository from my pc to the second account.

Comment: Have you seen also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7927828/3062311)?

Comment: what you have are probably different *github* accounts, don't you? Then they have very little to do with the config, you can even have both accounts used  for the same repository at same time.

Comment: after setting up ssh config try running `ssh -v git@github.com-activehacker` and same for another account. Github does not allow shell access but you will see if logging in succeeds and which key is used

Comment: Nope, nothing is working. Can anyone try to do the same from scratch i.e : create a second account at github and try to push repository on that using ssh keys / config file whatever needed.

Comment: Local or global config file ?
`subl ~/.gitconfig`

Answer (score 17):

Answer is

`git config --global -e`

it will open `.gitconfig` file in your default editor that you should have configured for git.

[git-config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)

[Table 4. Exhaustive list of core.editor configuration commands](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-C:-Git-Commands-Setup-and-Config)

Answer (score 10):

1. Navigate to your git repo
2. enter to `.git` folder -> `cd .git`
3. Open the `config` file as `vi config`
4. Add the following

`[user]
     name = YOUR_USER_NAME
     email = YOUR_EMAIL`

In your each repository, you can have different `git@User` and associated `git@email`

*** **Another way to set username and email to specific git repo**

To set your username for a **specific repository**, enter the following command in the **root folder of your repository**: -

`git config user.name "User_Name"
 git config user.email "your_email@example.com"`

**To set usernme as globally**

Open your console and run the following - 
`git config --list`

It will give you present git configuration status.

You can set `username` as **global**

`git config --global user.name "User_Name"
 git config --global user.email "your_email@example.com"`

Hope this would help your query

Comment: Thanks I tried it, but it's not helping. I can see ssh keys configured to my previous account only whenever I pushed my repositories to the second account.

Comment: Remove the ssh key and then try.

Comment: @user3363723 remove all user from `git configuration` and then add each user to your repo. What it is giving now?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple step that I used  to edit my git/config file

1. Open a terminal of your choice. You can also use the shortcut key `Ctrl+Alt+T` to open a terminal.
2. In your terminal type : `git config --global --edit` It will open your global configuration file of git in your default editor.
3. Change the Settings that you want.

For more info on git config, you can check the entire manual by typing `git config --help` in your terminal.

Answer (score 3):

For mac users - You can just run this command

`open ~/.gitconfig`