# Can't make 'git push' from cloned Github repository

Tags: git, github

I to signed in Github and clone repository from there. 
Then I made some corrections and commit them.
When I tried push changes to the server with such command

> git push origin master

I get following

> Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address
>   '192.30.252.129' to he list of known hosts. Permission denied
>   (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

In my Github settings I see following

> There are no deploy keys for this repository

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/

Comment: @Holloway  I maked this steps in Git Bash. 'ls -al ~/.ssh' command show me three SSH keys:
github_rsa
github_rsa.pub
known_hosts

Then I ran the command
eval $(ssh-agent -s)

ssh-add ~/.ssh/github_rsa

clip < ~/.ssh/github_rsa.pub

Then I added the keys to GitHub and make
ssh -T git@github.com

Did get the answer
Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
# provide shell access.


Then I repeated 'git push origin master' and again got

Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: Do you have permission to push to the repo? Is it yours?

Comment: No it not mine but I have permission.

Comment: The owner of the repository might need to add your key to their allowed committers list.

Comment: 'ssh -vT git@github.com' gives 'Permission denied (publickey)'

Comment: The owner said I am in allowed committers list.

Comment: You mention the key is called github_rsa. The default is id_rsa so you might have to specify the file. Try `ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/github_rsa git@github.com`

Comment: Answer: Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
# provide shell access.

Comment: Looks like that's the problem then. I'll write it into an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that git is looking for the default key file when doing the push but your key file is called something different (`github_rsa` instead of `id_rsa`). This in itself isn't an issue but if you don't have mutliple keys, you could just rename it (or create a symlink to it).

If you have multiple keys, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927750/specify-an-ssh-key-for-git-push-for-a-given-domain) question.

You need to set up an ssh config file (quite useful anyway) and use it to specify the key file to use. Something like

```
Host github
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile /home/whoever/.ssh/github_rsa
```

then use `github` instead of `git@github.com` in your push command/gitconfig

Comment: When I tried 'git push origin master' and enter a passphrase, I get this

! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:username/myproject.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
I did 'git pull' and repeat 'push' but got same message.

Comment: Did the pull compete successfully?

Comment: Now the pull complete successfully and the push too. Thank you very much.