# Git: access a remote repository over ssh using a key file but without using ~/.ssh/config

Tags: git, ssh, config

Is it possible to access (`fetch`/`push`) a remote repository using ssh and an identity file (with the private key) without adding an entry in the file `~/.ssh/config` such as:

```
Host tingle
  HostName 111.222.333.444
  User git
  IdentityFile c/tmp/my_id_rsa
```

Everything works fine when configuring the `~/.ssh/config` file. However we have a script which clones from a remote repo, checks out, starts testing, commits results and pushes them. The script need to run on any machine without touching the ssh config file.

Comment: Could you create a custom config file with what you have above that's only used where you need it (e.g. `ssh tingle -F my_custom_config`)?

Comment: This answer might be useful. I stumbled on it while looking for something similar earlier this week. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4565746/1789724

Comment: Check the post here:
>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927750/specify-an-ssh-key-for-git-push-for-a-given-domain

Answer (score 10):

You can use the variable `$GIT_SSH`, see the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables), to set a program that is invoked instead of ssh.

That way you can, e.g. do

`GIT_SSH=/my/own/ssh git clone https://my.own/repo.git`

Adapt the contents of `/my/own/ssh` to your own need, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Wrapper for ssh, to use identity file and known hosts file
exec /usr/bin/ssh -i /my/own/identity_file-o UserKnownHostsFile=/my/own/hosts.file "$@"
```

As far as I know this is currently the only way to do this without rather untidy path manipulations.

Comment: This works. Especially handy if our script creates an own host config file and add to the wrapper:  exec  /usr/bin/ssh - F our_ssh_host  "$@"

Answer (score 4):

You could override the `$GIT_SSH` environment variable to use your own private key:

First, create a wrapper script. Let assume we call it `gitssh.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -i /path/to/mykey "$@"
```

Then, point `$GIT_SSH` to it:

```
export GIT_SSH=/path/to/gitssh.sh
```

Now, whenever you run a git command over ssh, it will be substituted with this script, and references your key.

Answer (score 3):

The following should do the trick

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i c/tmp/my_id_rsa" git push
```

This allows you to add parameters to the ssh execution without the need of an additional script file.

Depending on your script you can fine tune this by defining and exporting the environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` before the actual execution of git or use `if` etc. to only use it when you are communicating with `tingle`

In your config file you mention user and host, too. This should already be part of the git remote definition. If you still need to override this you could add these to the above command definition.

One remark the command above is not checking which host actually is invoked by git. But if you are desperate you could try to build a inline shell script with this "trick" that checks the hostname and mimics the config file host restriction ;-).

As a starter that would maybe look like this:
`GIT_SSH_COMMAND="bash -c \"if [ \\\"$1\\\" = \\\"user@host\\\" ] ; then ssh -i c/tmp/my_id_rsa $@ ; else ssh $@ ; fi \"  --  " git push`

I didn't test this and be aware of quoting ;-). It's for the desperate.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a **custom ssh key** you can try with this:

```
ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /path/to/your/id_rsa; git clone git@github.com:repo'
```

In this way you **don't need** to write/edit any config file or modify your enviroment.