# Tell git which SSH config file to use

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

I have multiple ssh config folders for various systems e.g.:

```
ssh -F ~/.ssh/system-a/config user@system-a
ssh -F ~/.ssh/system-b/config user@system-b
```

Each folder has a config file and set of identity files like so

```
Host system-a
    HostName <some_hostname>
    User <some_username>
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/system-a/keys/system-a.pem
```

How do tell git to use a certain ssh config file or a certain ssh key when performing git tasks?

Ideally I would like to do this per git project if I can.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/232373/how-to-tell-git-which-private-key-to-use goes over how to tell git which ssh key to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify an SSH key for git push for a given domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927750/specify-an-ssh-key-for-git-push-for-a-given-domain)

Comment: @therobinkim nope, that explains how to make a segment for GitHub, not how to make git use a specific config file.

Comment: @pfwd did you by chance forget to accept the answer that fits your needs?

Answer (score 30):

on command-line you can change your Git config for the current repository:

```
git config core.sshCommand "ssh -F ~/.ssh/system-a/config"
```

or in `.git/config` in your local repository to the `[core]` section:

```
sshCommand = "ssh -F ~/.ssh/system-a/config"
```

This works only with git 2.10 and newer. Otherwise, it needs to be set up using environment variable `$GIT_SSH_COMMAND`, for example like:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -F ~/.ssh/system-a/config" git pull
```

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs Thanks for correction. I did't find the actual release notes and 2.9 did not have this feature.

Comment: I like to add the reference to the identify file I created for the GitHub repo directly so I use the -i option to ssh in the .git/config file. sshCommand = "ssh -i ~/.ssh/github_reponame_rsa"

Comment: Alternative, as for some reasons -F configuration did not work for me (git 2.25), I specified the ssh key directly using the -i option.

Answer (score 18):

I wanted to hook into this topic, because I have recently been trying to solve this without having to do a `git config core.sshCommand` every new release I clone

So, for that I extended a bit on the implementation from [Jakuje](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41219960/147407)

I have two gitlab accounts. One is for work, with my work email, and one is personal, with my personal email.

For this I have two different private keys:

- personal: `~/.ssh/keys/personal.id_rsa`
- work: `~/.ssh/keys/work.id_rsa`

Now, I have a global git configuration located at `~/.gitconfig` and an alternative configuration located at `~/work.gitconfig`. The work git configurations only contains settings that are different than the global configuration.

So in this scenario,

~/work.gitconfig

```
[core] 
    sshCommand = ssh -i ~/.ssh/keys/work.id_rsa
```

and all my work related repositories I clone into `~/source/work`

The magic then happens in my `~/.gitconfig`. I included the following section (git [`includeIf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_includes):

```
[includeIf "gitdir:~/source/work/**"]
    path="~/work.gitconfig"
```

Now, this will tell `git` to include my work git configuration for all repos that are in `~/source/work`. This configuration will then automagically set the ssh key used when pushing/pulling to the one I use for my work repos.

All you need to make sure is to clone into the right folder.

You can combine this with using a generic ssh config.

```
Host gitlab.com
    HostName gitlab.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keys/personal.id_rsa
```

By default git will use the `personal.id_rsa` (personal account), except when the repo is in the `work` directory, then the work account is used (based on ssh key).

Comment: This answer should be higher - [includeIf "glob_pattern"] is genius and solve my case completely without the need for additional configuration/tools.

Answer (score 16):

As Andrejs Cainikovs and Jakuje have pointed out, it is possible to use multiple ssh-config files with a recent enough `git`.

However, you can achieve virtually the same results with a single ssh-config file with multiple configurations, possibly all referring to a single real host:

```
Host SOMELABEL
    HostName <some_hostname>
    User <some_username>
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/system-a/keys/system-a.pem

Host OTHERLABEL
    HostName <other_hostname>
    User <other_username>
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/system-b/keys/system-a.pem
```

and then clone the repos like:

```
  git clone SOMELABEL:foo/bar.git
  git clone OTHERLABEL:frobnozzel.git
```

This will use `<some_username>@<some_hostname>` with the ssh-key in `~/.ssh/system-a/keys/system-a.pem` for the **`bar`** repository, whereas it will use `<other_username>@<other_hostname>` with the ssh-key in `~/.ssh/system-b/keys/system-a.pem` for the **`frobnozzel`** repository.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs i stand corrected (and have updated my answer); i still don't understand *why* multiple ssh-config-files would be preferred over a single one (but of course that's up to the @pfwd)

Comment: Of course, having a single `~/.gitconfig` and `~/.ssh/config` is the way to go. But I think the OP hit the corner case. Perhaps test automation, or something...

Comment: @umläute Its just the way I prefer to work. I like having separate config files and directories for my projects instead of lumping them all together

Comment: @umläute thank you for actually listing the `git clone` command. No other related answer does :)

Comment: That works, however you have to recognize that in order to use the `git@github.com` clone address, you must use the hostname of the address and the `git` user in your config file, so the `Host` directive should be set to `github.com` and the `User` directive should be set to `git` - otherwise you will not be able to clone using the `git@github.com` directive - same goes for other git remote addresses/hostnames.

Comment: sure, that's why i was using placeholders; also this question is not about github specifically but about using git+ssh in general. i don't think it would help much if i listed all the possible username/hostname combinations.

Answer (score 1):

**git 2.10+**

Check [Jakuje answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41219960/147407).

**git 2.9-**

Use `core.gitproxy` pointing to the custom script that does the magic.