# How to use 2 different GIT remote servers on same Ubuntu machine?

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, ssh, https

I am using my company stash account on my laptop. Sometime I develop my person project and I want to use my person Github account in those projects. I know how to use 2 different git remote servers by ssh keys from [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/manage-multiple-github-accounts-the-ssh-way-2dadc30ccaca)

But I do not want to play around with ssh keys. Is it possible I use GIT with HTTPS with my personal github account ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify an SSH key for git push for a given domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927750/specify-an-ssh-key-for-git-push-for-a-given-domain)

Comment: Not sure I understand the question here. Yes you can use https to clone you personal github account

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible I use GIT with HTTPS with my personal github account ?

Yes: simply change the remote URL from SSH to https:

```
cd /path/mto/my/repo
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<me>/myproject
```

Combine that with a [credential helper](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/caching-your-github-password-in-git#platform-linux) to cache the credentials.
I would recommend the GCM (Git Credential Manager) like one for [Mac/Linux](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Mac-and-Linux).
That way, you won't have to enter your GitHub account password every time you push to your remote repository.