# Git SSH to Github with a Config File Stuck in a Loop

Tags: git, github, ssh, emacs, magit

SSH commits to Github do work with my current setup. I use this recommended script to trigger the password prompt:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
 
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/github_ssh_private_key
```

However, ever since I switched to Emacs' Magit, password prompting simply didn't happen, I still don't know why. Apparently, the recommendation to fix this is to use a `~/.ssh/config` file — I use Artix Linux. Currently, my `config` file looks like this — even though I've tried many, many other variations —:

```
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile /home/philippe/.ssh/github_ssh_private_key
```

This simplifies the workflow overall, as a prompt now appears both in the terminal and on Emacs, i.e. I don't have to run the `eval ... ssh-agent` script anymore. However, typing my correct password simply doesn't achieve anything, the prompt reappears on the line below endlessly.

Strangely, the password/passphrase prompt changes slightly across the mentioned use cases:

```
Enter passphrase for /home/philippe/.ssh/github_ssh_private_key:       # with the eval script
Enter passphrase for key '/home/philippe/.ssh/github_ssh_private_key': # With the `config` file
```

I've seen a bazillion posts on the internet about this topic, but haven't found anything official or standardized about it so far. These are my references so far:

- [Magit how to use ssh key rather than being prompted for password](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/30876/33634)
- [Authentication on Github](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github)
- [A Gist on this Topic with a Bazillion Dissonant Solutions](https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996)

Comment: Does a regular `git pull` work? The files in the prompt and in the configuration seem to differ; are all paths correct? What's the output in Magit's log (`$`)?

Comment: `git pull` and `git clone` both seem to be working fine. Sorry for the typo in the filenames, `github_ssh_private_key` was supposed to be a friendlier version of `github_ssh`. I'm also going to include Magit's output next.

Comment: Magit actually enters the same prompt loop. Or, if I remove the `config` file, it returns a fatal error saying that I didn't have the necessary permissions to manage the repo.

Comment: "since I switched to Emacs' Magit, password prompting simply didn't happen" -- did you start Emacs in the environment which knew about your ssh-agent?  E.g. after running `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` did you then run `emacs` in the same terminal?  (Or otherwise import the ssh agent environment variables into Emacs -- you could also use `M-x setenv`).

Comment: @phils, I had not tried that. But, now that I did, it does work! Thanks. But how would I simplify this setup? How exactly could I share this `ssh-agent` with Emacs? Can it be done without launching it from a terminal?

Comment: Opening a terminal within Emacs and using the whole `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` ordeal doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: I'm not an emacs expert, and you should find someone who is for an "emacs-y" solution, but the root of the problem here is that when you use a service-enabled emacs, running `emacs somefile` ends up sending a request to the existing, already-open emacs to edit that file, rather than actually editing that file. The existing, already-open emacs has to have the right environment setup to talk to the ssh agent (because magit runs in *that* emacs, not the one you think you're using!).

Comment: One approach is to run the ssh-agent as part of your GUI login session, so that it's visible in the environment inherited by every process started within that session.  Failing that, you can arrange that your shell config will always configure/talk to a single common agent, so that anything you do from a shell will automatically know about that agent.  I believe that https://www.funtoo.org/Keychain can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

That needs to work in a terminal first, before Emacs.

I would add to the config file a `User git` line.

Once that is working, then you can check your [Emacs/Maggit configuration](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17890) and see if that helps.

Comment: Why would you need to add `User git`? I had tried with or without it and it didn't seem to make a difference. And the `ssh-add` comment is because I made another typo, which I've just fixed, I think.

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro It is just good practice: the user should always be `git` when it comes to SSH access to `github.com`

Comment: And where does that good practice come from? Is that something you picked up from your experience? Is there documentation about it somewhere about it?

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro I understand this is frustrating, and hope you will find a solution. Documentation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7927828/6309 and https://blog.mattclemente.com/2020/09/15/multiple-github-accounts-wildcard-ssh-config-identityfile.html

Comment: I don't know if my last message was misinterpreted but I didn't mean to lash out on anyone here. It's just that I find quite ridiculous that there are so many devs working out dissonant solutions to this problem and I can't seem to find a simple enough solution and explanation for all of its parts. Things look at best as someone trying to reverse-engineer the problem. It's 2021 and users have to scour the internet in order to find out how to do something which should be easily found in the Git or Github documentation.

Comment: I'd say this is based on Github's SSH addresses being `git@github.com:...` which is indeed specifying a user named `git`; so the config is consistent with that... *but* as github always makes that username explicit in the SSH remote addresses it displays, I suspect you'd need to go out of your way to make a SSH connection to github with any *other* username.