# Git custom SSH command

Tags: git, mercurial, ssh, custom-action, ssh-keys

I am trying to find a way to run git with a custom ssh command when needed. I do not want to use any configuration files or environmental variables. I would just like to use something like the `-e sshcommand` option than Mercurial gives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you use a custom ssh command line with `git` is:

- via the `GIT_SSH` environment variable, or
- by adding a stanza to `~/.ssh/config` that matches your target host

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496037/how-to-specify-which-ssh-key-to-use-within-git-for-git-push-in-order-to-have-git) explores the `GIT_SSH` solution in more detail.

There is otherwise no direct equivalent to the `-e` command line in Mercurial.