# Git Push fails permission issue for git account

Tags: git

I have two github account and when I try to clone and push, for some reason it fails with permission denied.

I have configured my ssh keys and I can verify that ssh works with

```
ssh -vvv git@github.com


git push -u origin

remote: Permission to <user-name-2>/test-config.git denied to <user-name-1>.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/<user-name-2>/test-config.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to push to a repository you are not allowed to push to. Check whether you have filesystem permissions on the server. If you're really trying to push to another users account on GitHub, afaik this is not allowed.

You must use the key of the other user. The following two Stack Overflow questions have answers about how to do something like this:

- [Specify an SSH key for git push for a given domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927750/specify-an-ssh-key-for-git-push-for-a-given-domain)
- [How to specify which SSH key to use within git for git push in order to have gitorious as a mirror?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496037/how-to-specify-which-ssh-key-to-use-within-git-for-git-push-in-order-to-have-git)

Comment: Both are my accounts and I have ssh keys configured and added in my .ssh

Comment: @RajeshJain I added some links which might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to my question from this thread
[Pushing to Git returning Error Code 403 fatal: HTTP request failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed)

```
git remote set-url origin https://yourusername@github.com/user/repo.git
```